# Convert HTML to PDF with httr

Tags: r, api, pdf, httr

I have an HTML file saved locally that I would like to convert to PDF using httr and pdfcrowd.com API.  I am using the following code:

```
library(httr)

r <- POST(url="http://pdfcrowd.com/api/pdf/convert/html/", config=list(authenticate(user=myusername, password=myAPItoken)), 
              encode="multipart", body=upload_file(path=< my local path >))

content(r)
```

When I run this I get the following output saying that I am missing the src field.  My understanding is the src field is the path to the file.  Any help is appreciated:

```
"No data to convert. Missing src field."
```

Comment: I'm not certain, but the help file says, for `encode`, *If the body is a named list, how should it be encoded?*, and your `body` is not a named list.  Don't know if it matters

Comment: [pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/installing.html) can do this _really_ well locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the documentation and error message, I suspect you want:

```
library(httr)

r <- POST(
  "http://pdfcrowd.com/api/pdf/convert/html/", 
  authenticate(myusername, myAPItoken), 
  body = list(src = upload_file("my local path"))
)

content(r)
```